# Complete C# noob, VS2010, cannot use HttpServerUtility.UrlEncode?

Tags: c#, urlencode, url-encoding

So, i'm a complete noob to C#. I have a url that i need to encode in order to use urlencoded posts.

Issue is, every resource i've found says to use System.Web.HttpServerUtility.UrlEncode. Alternatively, I have seen resources telling me to use System.Web.Util.HttpEncoder().

I have added a reference to system.web, but am getting the "does not exist in system.web namespace" and "does not exist in system.web.util namespace" errors.

Any tips would be nice!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using System.Web;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string url = HttpUtility.UrlEncode("http://stackoverflow.com/");
            MessageBox.Show(url);
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: You're misusing `UrlEncode`.  Use it to encode data values in querystring parameters.

Comment: When you say that you have "added a reference to system.web", are you sure you didn't just add a `using System.Web` clause to your code ? You need to add the reference to the assembly (DLL). (right click on your project, add reference)

Answer (score 6):

Chances are you're using the .NET 4 Client Profile, which doesn't include `System.Web.dll` - or you just haven't added a reference to it. If you go into the project properties, under "Application" select ".NET Framework 4" as the target framework, rather than ".NET Framework 4 Client Profile". You should then be able to add a reference to the `System.Web` assembly.

(Note that an assembly is *not* the same as a namespace. Assembly references are added to a project, whereas you typically "add" namespaces to an individual file with `using` directives at the top. You've already got the `using` directive for the `System.Web` namespace, but that won't help you use `HttpServerUtility` without a reference to the `System.Web` assembly.)

Alternatively, depending on your *exact* requirements, you could use [`Uri.EscapeDataString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.escapedatastring.aspx) or [`Uri.EscapeUriString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.escapeuristring.aspx). Both of these are available in the client profile. It's slightly annoying that there are so many different ways of doing this - it can be tricky to pick the right one :(

Comment: That was it! Thanks, after changing from Client Profile to .NET Framework 4, all went smoothly. Thanks again!

Answer (score 5):

You might need to add reference to the `System.Web` assembly to your project:

[image]

Comment: The screenshot won't really help him, since the "add reference" dialog is completely different in VS2010 (unless he's using the Express version)

Comment: Updated screenshot with VS 2010. Not so much different after all. In fact the main difference is invisible in the screenshot. It is in the speed. You no longer need to drink five coffees before seeing this window on previous versions of Visual Studio (thank you Microsoft).

Answer (score 1):

I believe you did *not* add the reference to System.Web.dll.

References and namespace imports are different things.
Namespace is a way to group related classes together, so all classes related to collections reside in System.Collections, all Windows Forms stuff is in System.Windows.Forms and you may also want to organize your project to separate business logic, presentation and data access in different namespaces.

However namespaces are purely logical. You can build several libraries that add classes to the same namespaces, and you can also use several namespaces in one project.

You imported **System.Web namespace** here with the *using* statement:

```
using System.Web;
```

It only means that instead of accessing the class by its *full name*, System.Web.HttpUtility, you can write just HttpUtility, and the compiler will infer you mean the System.Web one.

However, for Windows applications, the **library itself, called System.Web.dll** is not referenced by default. This means that none of System.Web classes are even known to the compiler right now.

To add a reference to physical library file, right-click on project *References* folder, choose '*Add Reference...*' and pick **System.Web.dll**.

And, again, namespaces are just logical groupings, assemblies are physical files on your hard drive.

Good luck,
Dan